# Flutter: 'file.existsSync()' seems to be always false on IOS-Devices when trying to upload a video to firebase_storage

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-storage

I'm trying to upload videos from the users gallery to firebase_storage.
Firstly, the user picks the video:

```
      final File file = await ImagePicker.pickVideo(
        source: ImageSource.gallery,
      );


      // Video compression
      MediaInfo info;
      if (Platform.isIOS) {
        info = await _flutterVideoCompress.getMediaInfo(file.path);
      } else {
        info = await _flutterVideoCompress.compressVideo(
          file.path,
          deleteOrigin: true,
          quality: VideoQuality.MediumQuality,
          includeAudio: true,
        );
      }

      setState(() {
      _galleryFile = info.file;
      });
```

After the video-file is selected (and on android compressed, ios does it automatically) the user can trigger the upload:

```
try {
  var timestamp = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString();
  var type = user.type;
  var typeString = type == 0 ? 'player' : type == 1 ? 'trainer' : 'club';

  String fileName = '${id}_$timestamp';
  StorageReference reference = FirebaseStorage.instance
      .ref()
      .child(typeString)
      .child(
          '$typeString-upload-${_fileType == 'video' ? 'video' : 'images'}')
      .child(id)
      .child(fileName);

  setState(() {
    isLoadingUpload = true;
  });

  _uploadTask = reference.putFile(_galleryFile, StorageMetadata(contentType: 'video/mp4'));

  .
  .
  .

catch (e) {
  print(e);
}
```

But the code already failes at `uploadTask = reference.putFile(_galleryFile, StorageMetadata(contentType: 'video/mp4'));` with 'file.existsSync() is not true'.
Tested on iPhone 7 and iPhone XR.
Everything works perfectly on android.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The same thing happens to me, but only if the video is shared from Google Photos, if it is shared from the iOS gallery, it works perfectly.